# What is the difference between transition-all and transition in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, tailwind-css

Tailwind offers multiple utilities for controlling which CSS properties transition, among these properties there are `transition` and `transition-all`.

I went and checked the CSS properties for both classes and here they are in the same order.

```css
transition-property: background-color, border-color, color, fill, stroke, opacity, box-shadow, transform, filter, backdrop-filter;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
transition-duration: 150ms;
```

```css
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
transition-duration: 150ms;
```

What is the difference between both classes and which one should I use for general transitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the difference you need to understand an important thing about animatable properties. Some of them trigger layout changes and some of them don't.

A property that trigger a layout change will have an impact on the performance so it's recommended to avoid them as much as possible

A property that doesn't trigger a layout change will have less impact on the performance and it's recommended to animate them.

The  `transition` class of tailwind is grouping the second set of properties (the ones that don't trigger layout change) while `transition-all` group all of them.

It's better to rely on `transition` to have good performance and you should avoid as much as possible `transition-all` but if you are obliged to animate *all* the properties then use it.

Here is a good reference to help you understand what I am talking about: https://csstriggers.com/

If you check for [`color`](https://csstriggers.com/color) you can read:

> Changing color does not trigger any geometry changes, which is good.

As a side note, `transform` is the best when it comes to performance. It doesn't trigger layout change and doesn't trigger painting:

> Changing transform does not trigger any geometry changes or painting, which is very good. This means that the operation can likely be carried out by the compositor thread with the help of the GPU.

Comment: is the same true for `transition-opacity`? Will that be more efficient than `transition`? I like the conciseness of `transition` but I don't want to trade off performance for it.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, Tailwind's `transition` class defines transitions for a limited set of CSS properties: `background-color`, `border-color`, `color`, `fill`, `stroke`, `opacity`, `box-shadow`, `transform`, `filter`, `backdrop-filter`.

When using `transition-all` all properties that can transition will - this includes all [animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) (properties in `transition` and much more).

Using one or the other will depend on which properties you want to animate, if they're all covered by `transition` then there's no need to use `transition-all`.

Answer (score 0):

I think If you need all properties its better to use `transition-all`
but if you want to be specific Use the `transition-{properties}` utilities to specify which properties should transition when they change.

e.g. `transition-color` going to be
`transition-property: background-color, border-color, color, fill, stroke;` as tailwind [doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property)

Comment: I am talking about the specific `transition` class, it references all properties as you can see in the CSS but still has a different syntax to `transition-all`. I am wondering if they are any different.