# What's the point of mentioning property name in shorthand transition in CSS

Tags: css, frontend, web-deployment

I can't figure out why some people mention property name in shorthand transition while it will be the same if they don't do that.

Lets say there is a button that I want to change its background

```
.btn{
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:hover{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

**transition: background .3s;** and **transition: .3s;** have the same result but why some people mention **background** ? Does it affect the performance ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#defining_transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> while it will be the same if they don't do that.

No it's not the same. A trivial example:

```css
.box {
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transform:scale(1);
}

.box:hover {
  transform:scale(1.5);
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="transition:0.3s;"></div>

<div class="box" style="transition:background 0.3s;"></div>
```

They only have the same result if we consider background but the first one cover **all** the properties and in many cases we don't need to transition all the properties but rather specific ones.

Related: [What is the difference between transition-all and transition in TailwindCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67363406/8620333)